# Trying to re-direct path of a file from c drive to tomcat apache server

Tags: java, eclipse, apache, tomcat

Is there a way to change the path of a file present in C folder in a java program and put it into tomcat apache server. This whole code is running on Eclipse IDE and a java program takes the path of a file which is present in C: of the local machine. Can I change that path and somehow store or re-direct that path from the Tomcat apache server.

We are running the code through tomcat apache server on the local machine, now we would like to implement CI/CD pipeline and host the code on rancher for which the code is hosted on gitlab first and then the pipeline starts. Is there a way I can change this path and store the file in tomcat apache server or re-direct the path of the file from the server. Or will the project face any problem when processing through the pipeline? I'm using eclipse as IDE. Any help is much appreciated.

```
private final static String Word2VecModelPath = "C:\\german.model";
 // change this path
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here:

```
private final static String Word2VecModelPath = "C:\\german.model"
```

That is not a "path" on a file system! At this point, it is nothing but a *string*, a sequence of character. You can turn to the operating system, and given the fact that this string resembles a directory in your local file system, you can then use the Java APIs the access the corresponding file.

Thing is: it doesn't really matter whether that file sits on a local machine, or on a remote system. What matters for your use case is that you can access it via your file system.

In other words: if your server writes its files to a network drive, and your client has access to that, then you just need to change that path string, to maybe point to a different drive.

But most likely, things are more complicated: because that resource isn't sitting on some file system you have access to.

And then you have to first talk to your server for example, and download that file from there.

In other words is: the first thing for you is to understand the **difference** between having access to a file in your local file system, and a resource that is owned by some server, and is only accessible to you **via** the APIs that this server offers.

Comment: thanks for your reply.. I have cloned the project from a git repository and german.model file was inside the project. And in the java file, it is mentioned as a string. Now if I make my changes in the project and push it to git do you think this will have a problem in the pipeline?

Comment: @u2m2 As I don't know that project I can't tell you what implications your changes will have. You should rather talk to the other people contributing to that project. Honestly: given the fact that your knowledge seems *extremely* limited at this point in time, I would be extremely careful about pushing changes anywhere. Changes are that you really dont understand what you are doing, and making changes that work locally for you might still very much affect other people. On other hand, **hardcoded** paths in source code ... that is a bad thing by itself.

Comment: I agree these things should not be hardcoded. But in general how to change path like these and re-direct it throught tomcat apache server. Should I configure something in server.xml?

Comment: @u2m2 That totally depends on the overall picture. What is that file used for? How is the tomcat server using it? You only said: "here is a file path in my java code". I can't tell you how you can change that, as I have no idea about the overall goals (and hint: most likely, that question is way too broad for this community). My intention is to give insights on that very basic level you are already struggling. I can't solve your problem because I have no idea what your REAL problem is.